# Windows Task Scheduler breaks batch commands

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have written a batch script to perform some basic file operations.

```
@ECHO OFF
@SET FILETOGET=L:\Some Folder\Another Folder\database\fieldfile.db
@SET FILEDEST=C:\ProgramData\FieldApp\database\%USERNAME%\

@IF NOT EXIST %FILEDEST% (
  mkdir "%FILEDEST%"
)

@IF EXIST %FILEDEST%fieldfile.db (
  DEL \Q "%FILEDEST%fieldfile.db"
)

@IF EXIST %FILETOGET% (
  cd "%FILEDEST%"
  C:\Windows\System32\tar.exe -zxvf "%FILETOGET%"
) ELSE (
  ECHO Failed to find file: %FILETOGET%
)
```

The issue that really is getting under my skin is that if I run this script manually...it works precisely as expected. However, if I have Task Scheduler attempt to run it, I the ELSE if the last IF block always fires and the end result is that my intended yield from the execution of the script is non-existent.

Does anyone know why Task Scheduler can't just run a script the same way that it would run via manual execution? This is really driving me nuts!

Comment: to start with, I guess `L` is a network share, so task scheduler may not have permissions. more, if task is run when no user is logged in, there are not user environment, nor mapped drives.

Comment: to solve, first use `unc` paths when possible, or map drives at the beggining of your script (`cd` or better `pushd`). second, if permissions is an issue, run task under some account with privileges to use network resource.

Comment: also you have spaces in your paths. use preferred syntax `set “varname=varcontent”`. decorated quotes not intended

Comment: Neither of the `IF EXIST` commands will work if the file paths have spaces.

Comment: …unless you put quotation marks around them…

Comment: Numerous sources of excellent advice here! @elzooilogico - I changed the pathing to a UNC form and that did work great.
Mofi's advice - I removed the -v and again...that worked great! Also removed the \Q as per your suggestion as a single file deletion worked without prompting.